# Problema: No name 'departamentos' in module 'funcionario.apps'

Tags: python, django

## Não consigo passar desta fase, pois ao compilar apresenta o erro : No name 'departamentos' in module 'funcionario.apps'

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .apps.departamento.models import Departamento


class Funcionario(models.Model):
    nome =  models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Nome do Funcionario')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    departamentos = models.ManyToManyField(Departamento)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, o erro é auto-descritivo.

O que ele diz é que não há o nome "departamento"  - o prefixo `.apps` diz ao Python - a linguagem - que no diretório onde está esse arquivo aí - que possivelmente está em outra "app" do Django, há uma pasta `apps`, e dentro dessa pasta ele poderia encontrar um diretório com nome `departamentos` ou um arquivo chamado `departamentos.py`. Não é o caso - se seu projeto Django está estruturado da forma descrita nas documentações para o Django, você tem uma "app" "departamentos" irmã da app "funcionarios" uma pasta acima.

O import funcionará se você importar o pacote "departamentos" diretamente, uma vez que o Django configura o Pythonpath para achar as apps instaladas no projeto:

```
from departamento.models import Departamento
```

Salvo engano, o ORM do Django também é esperto o suficiente para achar o modelo a partir de uma string, com o nome_da_app.nome_do_modelo - nesse caso, você nem precisa do import  -apenas mudar sua declaração do campo para:

```
departamentos = models.ManyToManyField("departamentos.Departamento")
```

(o ORM do Django tem essa funcionalidade - o "salvo engano" é que não me recordo se tem que ser colocada mais alguma coisa na string para endereçar o outro model corretamente).